# How can i change betwen two or more slideshows?

Tags: jquery, html, css, slideshow, carousel

More exact is want to make a carousel that changes betwen more slideshows. I grouped by a class several images (a group of 3 images with class project1, a group with another 3 images with class project2 etc). In my carousel one group make an automatic slideshow but when i click next/back button i want that in the same container to change the group that shows. 
As an example i have a group with lion images that go one after another and when i click next i want them to change in a group of photos with cats for example. Is just a rough description to understand it better.

My Jquery for now:

```
function slideswitch() {
    var $active = $("#project img.project1.active");
    $active.hide();
    if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#project IMG.project1:last');

    var $next =  $active.next(":has(.project1)").length ? $active.next()
        : $('#project IMG.project1:first');

    $active.addClass('last-active').show();

    $next.css({opacity: 0.0})
        .addClass('active')
        .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() {
            $active.removeClass('active last-active');
        });
};
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(slideswitch, 2000 );
});
```

I also have a fiddle that is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sdGhT/10/).

Comment: Using circular buffer can be a good idea here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a fiddle that switches between 2 shows. The CSS is unchanged, but there is a change to the HTML and I added new JS functions and optimised your slideswitch function as it wasn't correctly finding slides

HTML changes (add onclick events)

```
<div id="back" onclick="changeShow('back');">B</div><div id="next" onclick="changeShow('next');">N</div>
```

JS

```
// current project and total amount of projects we have
var project = 1, projects = 1;

function changeShow(direction)
{
    // change project based on direction
    if (direction == 'back') {
        // check if previous project exists, otherwise use last as we would've cycled
        project = (project - 1 > 0) ? (project - 1) : projects;
    } else {
        // check we aren't exceeding the number of projects we have, otherwise loop
        project = (project + 1 <= projects) ? (project + 1) : 1;
    }

    // remove any active images from the old project
    $('#project img').removeClass('active last-active');

    // force slide change
    slideShow();
}

function getProjects()
{
    // find the largest project assuming they will be sequential - project1, project2, projectX..
    $('img[class^="project"]').each(function(){
        var current = parseInt($(this).attr('class').replace('project', ''), 10);
        if (current > projects) {
            // update projects count
            projects = current;
        }
    });
}


function slideShow()
{    
    var $active = $('.project' + project + '.active');
    if ($active.length == 0) $active = $('.project' + project + ':last');
    var $next = $active.next('.project' + project).length ? $active.next() : $('.project' + project + ':first');
    $active.addClass('last-active').show();
    $next.css({opacity: 0.0})
        .addClass('active')
        .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() {
            $active.removeClass('active last-active');
        });
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
    // find out how many projects we have
    getProjects();
    // start slide show
    setInterval(slideShow, 2000 );
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sjdaws/4QcYE/

Comment: Awesome and almost there. Since your already familiar with the code, isn't there a way to make a smoother transition ?

Comment: A smoother transition between shows or between slides? What behaviour would you like it to have?

Comment: Between shows. I tried n animations but overflow:hidden and border-radius doesn't seem to go together in opera and IE :| more efficient and more intuitive would be a different transition between shows. if you have an ideea would be perfect but thx for your contribution even so :)

Comment: The most reliable animation betwen project would be that the next project to grow from center. I'm trying on my own for now. But any sugestions are welcomed :)

Comment: I've updated it so the new project slides in. This is about the best I can do, not really much of a jQuery animator http://jsfiddle.net/4QcYE/2/